# UICollectionViewFlowLayout sections as columns rather than rows

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm trying to create a UICollectionView of two columns (of potentially different lengths) with the property that when a cell is deleted the cells below (rather than the cells to the right) move up to take its place. I have considered customising the layout using layoutAttributesForElementsInRect etc but don't want to do this if there's an easier way.

Basically all I need is the transpose of the standard FlowLayout with each section a new column instead of a new row. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible using `UICollectionView` without customizing the collection view layout based on your needs. `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` is a line breaking layout that means, it places all your cells along a line and break that line to the bounds of the collection view one by one. So you can place two cells in a row by adjusting the cell size and section insects. Even though it wont allow you adjust the cell during the deletion as your need. Obviously the adjacent cell will take place the position when deleting a cell. Can you go with two collection views side by side instead of one??